# How to combine objects without losing specific properties

Tags: node-editor, objects

I want to create a bunch of Marbles, each has three colored blades inside. The blades are connected to a Color Ramp and Random Node, the orb has its own node setup.

How can I combine these objects without losing the effects I get from the nodes? Joining gives the blades just one color, parenting does not copy the blades when creating instances.

[image: Marble with colored blades]

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this, is to put the four objects into a Collection.
You can duplicate the Collection or use it in a Particle System. Select Collection >Whole Collection to make sure that all the objects stay together as one.

Comment: You can also create a collection instance after you grouped them under one collection with Add > Collection Instance > _Your collection_ that way you only have to worry about one object.